# Reference request: (categorical) commutative algebra text

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I'd like a text that puts commutative algebra in a categorical framework. I'm wondering if anybody has any recommendations.

Comment: Try COMMUTATIVE ALGEBRA by David Eisenbud , not exactly what you asked but you might like it

Comment: You could start with a textbook on abelian categories. But at some point you're going to have to actually do some calculations with modules and rings...

Comment: Commutative algebra is a very detailed study of commutative rings. While the categorical language is unavoidable, «very categorical» does not mean much in that context. A good plan would be to learn commutative algebra from one of the good textbooks on the subject, and to do it with your categorically-minded point of view. On the other hand, it is usually a *bad* plan to start out on a subject one is not familiar with imposing on it constaints and limitations which, if one is somewhat unlucky, are not very sensible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the section "Commutative algebra in a cocomplete tensor category" in my thesis ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716)) is what you want?

Comment: Question: "I'd like to learn some commutative algebra". Now read your answer  — do you really think anyone can learn commutative algebra  (say, enough to understand a proof of the Cohen structure theorem or the Auslander-Buchbaum-Serre theory on cohomological characterization of local regular rings *ab ovo* reading your (very nice) thesis?

Comment: I think that the question is about a categorical introduction to commutative algebra, and *not* a complete treatment of the foundations of commutative algebra in the *usual sense* which finally leads to Cohen structure theorems and alike. But in the end, we will let the OP decide on this.

Comment: Martin is right; this is really what I meant. Also your thesis is very nice!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, well,  my point is that that part of your thesis is not an introduction to commutative algebra (or to anything else, really!), categorical or not.

Answer (score 5):

**[A Term of Commutative Algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385313/175094)**
By *Allen ALTMAN and Steven KLEIMAN* is quite updated and elegant book, which treats the subject with a categorical viewpoint and covers everything Atiyah-Macdonald offers. Also, the ebook is freely available online.